# Zend FrameWork 2 cant load layout.phtml

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

i use `zendframework2` ,my code is ok locally, but after upload my source code to server and enable mode rewrite on apache and installing requirement with composer and , connecting to database

i got this error on my server

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/test/www/module/Application/config/../View/layout/layout.phtml' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/test/www/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php on line 501
```

what should i do ?

i checked apache modules checked file permissions and everything is ok

Comment: is path really ok? I think it should be: *view* instead of *View*.

Comment: @venca thank you my friend my problem solved but the question is why in my local use with mamp server its ok ?why local is not case sensitive?

Comment: @venca post your answer to i accept it

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in [case-sensitive OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_preservation). You should try *view* instead of *View*.